# Site doesn't see available updates

Tags: 7, updating

I checked for available module updates on my non-production site and the site returned: "All of your projects are up to date."
But I know for sure that some of the modules are outdated, hence the site simply doesn't see these updates. For example, I checked one module's .info file and saw that it was fine.

Here's the configs:

> name = File Entity description = "Extends Drupal file entities to be
>   fieldable and viewable." package = Media core = 7.x
>
> dependencies[] = field dependencies[] = file dependencies[] = ctools
>   dependencies[] = system (>=7.33)
>
> test_dependencies[] = token test_dependencies[] = views
>
> files[] = views/views_handler_argument_file_type.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_rendered.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_type.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_filter_file_type.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_filter_schema_type.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_filename.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_link.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_link_edit.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_link_delete.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_link_download.inc files[] =
>   views/views_handler_field_file_link_usage.inc files[] =
>   views/views_plugin_row_file_rss.inc files[] =
>   views/views_plugin_row_file_view.inc files[] = file_entity.test
>   files[] = file_entity_views.test
>
> configure = admin/config/media/file-settings
>
> ; We have to add a fake version so Git checkouts do not fail Media
>   dependencies version = 7.x-2.x-dev
>
> ; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2018-02-11
>   version = "7.x-2.16" core = "7.x" project = "file_entity" datestamp =
>   "1518385686"

How can I make the site see the updates? Thank you.

UPDATE:

[image]

Here's what drush pm-updatestatus returned:

> The following theme is missing from the file system: 
>   [warning] class="placeholder">adminimal. For information about
>   how to fix this, see [the
>   documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215). bootstrap.inc:1143 Checking available update
>   data ...                                   [ok] Checking available
>   update data for Drupal.                           [ok] Checking
>   available update data for Administration menu (admin_menu). [ok]
>   Checking available update data for Administration menu Adminimal
>   [ok] Theme (adminimal_admin_menu). Checking available update data for
>   Backup and Migrate                [ok] (backup_migrate). Checking
>   available update data for Better Exposed Filters            [ok]
>   (better_exposed_filters). Checking available update data for Block
>   Title Link                  [ok] (block_titlelink). Checking available
>   update data for Chaos tools (ctools).             [ok] Checking
>   available update data for CAPTCHA (captcha).                [ok]
>   Checking available update data for Checklist API (checklistapi).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for CKEditor (ckeditor).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Colorbox (colorbox).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Google Analytics Contact Form 
>   [ok] (contact_google_analytics). Checking available update data for
>   Context (context).                [ok] Checking available update data
>   for Date (date).                      [ok] Checking available update
>   data for Devel (devel).                    [ok] Checking available
>   update data for Dropfort Update (dropfort_update).[ok] Checking
>   available update data for @font-your-face (fontyourface).   [ok]
>   Checking available update data for Email (email).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Entity API (entity).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Features (features).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Feeds (feeds).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Field Group (field_group).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Field Slideshow
>   (field_slideshow).[ok] Checking available update data for File Entity
>   (file_entity).        [ok] Checking available update data for Form
>   block (formblock).           [ok] Checking available update data for
>   Google Analytics Tokenizer        [ok] (ga_tokenizer). Checking
>   available update data for Google Analytics                  [ok]
>   (google_analytics). Checking available update data for HubSpot Drupal
>   integration        [ok] (hubspot). Checking available update data for
>   Panels (panels).                  [ok] Checking available update data
>   for Imagecache Token                  [ok] (imagecache_token).
>   Checking available update data for IMCE (imce).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Job Scheduler (job_scheduler).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for jQuery Update (jquery_update).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Libraries (libraries).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Link (link).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Media (media).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Menu Block (menu_block).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Metatag (metatag).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Microdata (microdata).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Module filter (module_filter).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Module Missing Message Fixer
>   [ok] (module_missing_message_fixer). Checking available update data
>   for Node export (node_export).        [ok] Checking available update
>   data for Nodequeue (nodequeue).            [ok] Checking available
>   update data for Pathauto (pathauto).              [ok] Checking
>   available update data for Pathologic (pathologic).          [ok]
>   Checking available update data for Phone (phone).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for PHPMailer (phpmailer).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for reCAPTCHA (recaptcha).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Reroute emails
>   (reroute_email).   [ok] Checking available update data for Schema.org
>   (schemaorg).           [ok] Checking available update data for Search
>   404 (search404).           [ok] Checking available update data for
>   Security Review (security_review).[ok] Checking available update data
>   for Site map (site_map).              [ok] Checking available update
>   data for Site Verification (site_verify).  [ok] Checking available
>   update data for SMTP Authentication Support       [ok] (smtp).
>   Checking available update data for Superfish (superfish).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Text Resize (text_resize).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Token (token).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Universally Unique ID (uuid). 
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Views (views).
>   [ok] Checking available update data for Views Responsive Grid
>   [ok] (views_responsive_grid). Checking available update data for Views
>   Slideshow (views_slideshow).[ok] Checking available update data for
>   Webform (webform).                [ok] Checking available update data
>   for XML sitemap (xmlsitemap).         [ok] Checking available update
>   data for Omega (omega).                    [ok]  Name
>   Installed Version  Proposed version  Message            Devel (devel) 
>   7.x-1.5            7.x-1.6           Update available   File Entity            7.x-2.16           7.x-2.22          Update available   (file_entity)                                                                  Link (link)            7.x-1.4            7.x-1.5           Update
>   available   Media (media)          7.x-2.16           7.x-2.19
>   SECURITY UPDATE
>                                                                available          Metatag (metatag)      7.x-1.22           7.x-1.25          Update
>   available   PHPMailer (phpmailer)  7.x-3.0-beta4      7.x-3.1
>   Update available   Views (views)          7.x-3.18           7.x-3.20 
>   Update available   Webform (webform)      7.x-4.16           7.x-4.17 
>   Update available

Comment: Hey hey, welcome to DA. It's a little bit confusing why you would post a modules `*.info.yml` here. Please ensure you have the Update Manager module enabled. Then add a screenshot of `example.com/admin/modules/update` to your question. Also, please add what `drush pm-updatestatus` returns you.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the extra info. The Update Manager is enabled. I've showed *.info because one time a site didn't want to see updates because that file was corrupt and I had to manually fix it.

Comment: See? Drush worked. Numerous `Update available` notifications. So, now back-up your code and database, and then run `drush up`. That's it.